# Name of the Spring XML file in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web

I'm new to Spring MVC and when i'm going through tutorials in different tutorials they name spring XML file in different names. As examples "spring-web-servlet.xml",  "dispatcher-servlet.xml", "spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml". Can somebody explain to me why is that.

Comment: Note that any tutorials that show configuration with XML are outdated. Spring Boot and Java configuration make it so you need very little setup at all. I recommend looking at the official Spring Boot Getting Started guides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What barunsthakur has answered is a means to change the default location of the spring configuration file by using the context param `contextConfigLocation`. If this param is not specified, spring mvc expects the following

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your
>   web application
>
> Consider the following DispatcherServlet Servlet configuration (in the
>   web.xml file):

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>golfing</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>golfing</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/golfing/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> With the above Servlet configuration in place, you will need to have a
>   file called /WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml in your application

Your projects most likely use default configurtion and in this case you must pair the name of your configuration file, with the servlet-name of your `DispatcherServlet`

you can read more in the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)

Answer (score 3):

The name of spring xml file doesn't matter. You can name it anything(something semantic will be good) and need configure the web.xml using same name. for e.g if the filename is `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` the add this entry in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: but in eclipse IDE I created two projects. Spring XML in one project as "dispatcher-servlet.xml" and in next one  "spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml". same codes in both projects. First one gives error while second one giving expected output. why is that???

Comment: updated the answer. check if you have provided the correct filename.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we need to add the listener also. Please correct me if I am wrong.

    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Otherwise we can mention the custom context config file location through an init param to the DispatcherServlet for "contextConfigLocation".

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.bankmanagement" />
```

Comment: This is the basic content for servlet.xml.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Comment: xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

Answer (score -1):

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:message"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bms1"/>
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="bookDao" class="com.hcl.dao.BookDaoImpl"> <property name="sessionFactory" 
    ref="sessionFactory" /> </bean> -->

<!-- <bean id="bookService" class="com.hcl.service.BookServiceImpl"> <property 
    name="bookDao" ref="bookDao"></property> </bean> -->
```

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

Comment: <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>
  <mapping class="com.cts.bankmanagement.entity.UserDetails" />
  <mapping class="com.cts.bankmanagement.entity.TransactionDetails" />
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>